# Second Page does not refresh data after going back to the first page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I have a list on Page 1 populated by using a MVVM pattern with details on Page 2. Initially when I select an item on Page 1, it is able to navigate to Page 2 and show the details. After hitting the Back button, if I select another item from Page 1, it navigates to Page 2 but shows the previous data instead of the data for the newly selected item.

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Following is the code, page 1

```
private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    var getscoreDataGroups = await GetScoreDataSource.GetGroupsAsync();
    this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = getscoreDataGroups;         
}

private void lvLiveMatch_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var itemId = ((LiveDataItem)e.ClickedItem).MatchID;
    if (!Frame.Navigate(typeof(MatchPage), itemId))
    {
       //throw new Exception(this.resourceLoader.GetString("NavigationFailedExceptionMessage"));
    }
}
```

Following is the code on page 2

```
private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        string matchid = e.NavigationParameter.ToString();
        if (matchid != "")
        {
            var getscoreMatchGroups = await GetScoreMatchSource.GetGroupsAsync(matchid);
            this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = getscoreMatchGroups;
        }
    }
```

While debugging, I get the correct value but the page 2 does not refresh with the new data.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do..

Comment: @Fred Navigating from Page 1 > Page 2 on listview click is showing me the correct data. When I then come back to Page 1 and then click another listview, the Page 2 does not show the newer data but only shows the older data

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to raise `PropertyChanged` of the ViewModel when the page is reloaded.

You can find a simple example [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WPF-Frame-Navigation-Cache-47337921) from msdn